# JBoss EAP 7.1 Windows service not started at System reboot

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, networking, jboss

I have a JBoss EAP 7.1 server running on a Windows 2010 machine. I have created windows service for JBoss start in automate mode and while restarting the system few times JBoss started but few time service not started i am getting the below error

> MSC000001: Failed to start service org.wildfly.network.interface.public: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service org.wildfly.network.interface.public: WFLYSRV0082: failed to resolve interface public

Standalone:

```xml
    <interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:myip}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:myip}"/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>
```

I defined **myip** in host file.

Could you please help us to resolve the issue?

Comment: Try setting the service to "Delayed Start"

Comment: i tried "Delayed Start" that's not worked